# Google Chrome GCM registration doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-messaging

I have problem with GCM registration in Google Chrome. I've created minimal example:

*manifest.json*

```
{
  "name": "TestGCM",
  "version": "0.1",
  "description": "Desc.",
  "permissions": ["gcm"],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": true
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

*background.js*

```js
var gcmSenderId = "782709818071";

var registerGcm = function(gcmRegistrationId) {
    console.log("registerGcm start");
    var lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;
    if (lastError) {
        console.error("Error during registering GCM token: ", lastError.message);
    }
    console.log("registerGcm end");
};

var senderIds = [gcmSenderId];
console.log("registering GCM...");
chrome.gcm.register(senderIds, registerGcm);
console.log("...");

var lastError = chrome.runtime.lastError;
if (lastError) {
    console.error("Error: ", lastError.message);
}
```

After I load this extension I only see:

```
registering GCM...
...
```

Registration doesn't work. I tried resetting Google Chrome settings to factory, reinstalling Chrome, restarting PC.
In *chrome://gcm-internals/* I see that GCM client state is UNINITIALIZED:

```
Android Id  
User Profile Service Created    true
GCM Enabled true
GCM Client Created  true
GCM Client State    UNINITIALIZED
Connection Client Created   false
Connection State    
Registered App Ids  
Send Message Queue Size 0
Resend Message Queue Size   0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a chance that you are dealing with corrupted GCM store. If this is a signed-in (see below) profile, and GCM Client is still shown as UNINITIALIZED, that would be the case. A way to deal with that is to go a corresponding  profile's folder and delete the GCM Store folder. Restarting Chrome should reinitialize GCM for the signed in profile, and your application should be able to work.

My only concern about that solution is that you mentioned that you reinstalled Chrome, which I would expect to delete the folders and this solution would not address the problem. On an off chance that you are using the old profile and it happens to be corrupted, please try these steps.

GCM Client in desktop Chrome is built in a way, that you don't need to be signed-in to have GCM running, it is enough to have an app/extension using GCM, but signing in and enabling Chrome Sync is an easy way to test that GCM works properly. That is the only reason I am recommending it.

Comment: Thank You my extension started working when I deleted GCM Store folder I don't know why it wasn't removed while uninstalling Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Check this documentation about [Implementing GCM Client on Chrome](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/chrome/client#obtain_gcm_registration_id), to know the basic steps you need to obtain GCM registration token.

It's explained here the steps and key points that you need to register the GCM. It has a sample code that you can use or serve as a guide for your project.

Also make sure that the enable API that you use is **"Google Cloud Messaging for Android"**. Because **"Google Cloud Messaging for Android"** will give you access to the normal GCM API. **"Google Cloud Messaging for Chrome"** won’t (it’s used for Chrome Apps in the Chrome Web Store).

Also check this [tutorial](http://chrome-apps-doc2.appspot.com/apps/cloudMessaging.html) on how to use Google Cloud Messaging in Chrome.